# How can I get function name from CallInst in LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I have an object of type `CallInst`. How can I get the name of the called function (aka callee). Assume the function is called directly (i.e., no indirect function calls).

Answer (score 27):

```
StringRef get_function_name(CallInst *call)
{
    Function *fun = call->getCalledFunction();
    if (fun) // thanks @Anton Korobeynikov
        return fun->getName(); // inherited from llvm::Value
    else
        return StringRef("indirect call");
}
```

anyway, that's what the documentation implies:

- [CallInst](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html)

  - [CallInst::getCalledFunction](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a0bcd4131e1a1d92215f5385b4e16cd2e)
- returns [Function](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html)
- and walk back up the inheritance graph until you see a plausible candidate:

  - [Value](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html)
  - [Value::getName](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#ad452febc1ac0b394876e640ec03ffa38)

Comment: Note that fun can be NULL here in case of indirect call.